# Javascript recursion only firing once

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I have the following code to run through a JSON tree and get the needed keys. I have 8 keys that are "complexType" (has a tree node with more elements) but the recursion only works once. All other iteractions are not called.

```
function getStructure(json){
    sequence = json["sequence"]["element"]        
    for(i=0;i<sequence.length;i++){
        innerSequence = sequence[i]         
        if(innerSequence["complexType"] != undefined){
            getStructure(innerSequence["complexType"])
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the full json file https://jsoncompare.com/#!/simple/id=d1c3517a3a50be7cb05bd343d1eab848/

Comment: what have you tried to debug this ? please include some debug attempts to your post, as stack overflow is not a code writing/debugging service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping with a global variable! In JavaScript all references and assignments that are not declared with `var`, `let` or `const` are global.

Thus whenever `getStructure` gets called `i` gets reset back to 0 for all instances. The variables `sequence` and `innerSequence` are also globals.

In addition your function name indicates that it shoudl return something other than `undefined`, which it currently returns.

There are missing semicolons. You should program with "use strict" to avoid that the engine dictates how to interpret your programn rather than you.

Comment: I added the "use strict" and declared all variables prior using them and the problem is solved! Thank you very much!